# Permanently storing an environment variable when using CMake install

Tags: c++, cmake, installation

I'm trying to store a path environment variable to the location of some configuration files my program needs at runtime, but I do not know the location of until the compiled program is installed.

My idea was to use the following:

```
install(CODE "set(ENV{MY_CONFIG_PATH} \"${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/MyConfig\"")
```

However, I quickly found out that this does not permanently set that environment variable so as soon as I run the program and check the contents of `MY_CONFIG_PATH` with `std::getenv()`, I get a null pointer.

I thought about maybe setting a preprocessor define at compile time, but that won't work either because it seems `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is only populated when the installation process is executing.

Can anyone suggest a neat workaround that works for both Windows and Unix?

Comment: `because CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is only populated when the installation process is executing.` - Variable *CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX* is **known** at *configuration stage*. Using `configure_file` you may embed its value into source/header file, and compile along with your program.

Comment: Works great. If you want to make a full answer of this I'll accept it.

Comment: Also just found `add_definitions(-DFOO -DBAR ...)` if that helps future viewers. In my case, I'd use it like: `add_definitions(-DMY_CONFIG_PATH="${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/MyConfig")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is known at configure-time you can use the [`configure_file`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/configure_file.html) command to configure a file and insert the value of `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` into the specified location.